# converter varchar para date oracle plsql

Tags: sql, oracle, pl-sql

Preciso converter um `varchar` para `date` para assim poder filtrar todas as datas maiores que uma certa data, por exemplo:

Quero todas as datas que sejam maiores que novembro de 2018 sejam listadas, estou fazendo da seguinte forma:

```
DATA_FINAL > TO_DATE('10/11/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

Porém sempre me é retornado o erro:

> ORA-01843: not a valid month

O que devo fazer? agradeço desde já.

Resultado do  `SUBSTR`:

```
    1   09
    2   08
    3   04
    4   26
    5   28
    6   07
    7   17
    8   13
    9   11
    10  12
    11  01
    12  18
    13  21
    14  16
    15  31
    16  20
    17  22
    18  29
    19  19
    20  25
    21  02
    22  05
    23  03
    24  10
    25  15
    26  14
    27  27
    28  06
    29  24
    30  30
    31  23
```

Comment: Se executar: `select TO_DATE('10/11/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY') from dual` também ocorre o erro? Se não ocorrer (como não ocorreu comigo) o campo `DATA_FINAL` está preenchido em algum registro com data inválida.

Comment: Eu fiz esse select aqui e funcionou sem problemas. Há alguma coisa gravada nesse campo DATA_FINAL que esta causando o erro.

Comment: select TO_DATE('10/11/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY') from dual funciona, porem no select da o erro que falei, e pelo que vi não tem data nenhuma com formato errado.

Comment: Faça o select de apenas algumas linhas. Eu acho que vai funcionar. Até que você selecione a linha que DATA_FINAL esteja inválida.

Comment: Se suas datas estão no formato americano seu to_date esta 100% correto! Um possível teste seria substituir o to_date por um Sysdate apenas para verificar se o erro persiste, eliminando a formatação de data e etc. Outro detalhe, o campo Data_final é do tipo date correto?

Comment: Minha data ta no formato pt-br porem das 2 formas acontece o erro

Comment: Confundir, o campo DATA_FINAL é do tipo VARCHAR, estou convertendo para date

Comment: DATA_FINAL > SYSDATE tb da a mensagem de erro

Comment: Faça esse select e poste o resultado: select distinct substr( data_final, 1, 2 ) from sua_tabela

Comment: Reginaldo Rigo, postei o resultado na parte de cima.

Comment: Pelo que entendi a primeira coluna é a linha e a segunda o resultado do substr. Certo? Se for isso mesmo. todos os numeros acima de 12 estão inválidos porque você esta tentando converte-los para mês. Por isso a mensagem: NOT A VALID MONTH.

Comment: Reginaldo Rigo, mas eu troquei de mm/dd/yyyy para dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: Se ainda assim deu errado é porque ainda esta inválida. Verifque se o conteudo do select distinct substr( data_final, 3 ,2 ) vem alguma coisa diferente de 1 a 12

Comment: @StandAlone, mas desta maneira você esta comparando uma string com uma data, o correto seria converter o campo varchar para date também. Se não for muito trabalhoso, é aconselhável você converter esta coluna para o tipo date, gravar data em formato string é abrir uma porta para mil problemas diferentes ...

Answer (score 1):

--este bloco lista as datas que não estão no formata esperado

```
set serveroutput on;--se sql plus, senao setar o output na ferramenta

declare
  vd date;
begin
  for r in (select data_final from tabela)
    loop
      begin
        vd := to_date(r.data_final,'mm/dd/yyyy');
      exception
        when others then
          dbms_output.put_line('data com erro' || r.data_final);
      end;
    end loop;
end;
```

ao menos terá o que gera o problema

Comment: o resultado foi o numero 14... nao entendi...

Comment: 14 não é uma data válida no formato esperado.

Comment: Não tem, coloquei na condição DATA_FINAL = '14' e não acha nada.

Comment: Data Like '%14' and length(trim(data)) < 3